# Question-tag structure for "should not have scolded"?

Tags: tag-questions

What should be an appropriate question-tag to use for the following sentence:

> *You should not have scolded the child.*

I want to go with "should you have?" but the Teachers' Textbook I refer to says "should you?" I know that that is wrong, but is it really?

Comment: Your textbook is right. You should parse the sentence this way but : You/should not/ have scolded/the child. Whether you have "scold" or "have scolded"  doesn't change anything to the tag question.

Answer (score 4):

Everybody will understand if you say:

> You should not have scolded the child, shouldn't you have?

there's nothing grammatically wrong with it, but it is not usual to have two auxiliaries in this sort of tags. And I would advise you strongly not to use it in an EFL exam.

The tag is built with the auxiliary that has the most influence on the meaning of the sentence. In your example **have** is the auxiliary that helps build the present perfect **tense**, it only modifies "scold (the child)".
**Should** is a **modal** auxiliary, it helps expressing the speaker's opinion towards the action that follows (in your sentence reproach towards "you"). It influences the whole group:  present perfect verb ("have scolded") plus object ("the child").  The modal takes precedence over the tense auxiliary.

Other examples:

> You can't have eaten the whole cake, can you?
>   He'll be coming shortly, won't he?

Your next question might be: what about if we have two modals, in the same verb group? Well, that is grammatically impossible in English. When two different modalities have to be expressed, one of the modal verbs is replaced by a lexical verb.
Let's say we want to express the idea of *advice* (indicated in English by modal "should") together with *ability* (expressed by modal "can"). In that case we substitute the modality usually expressed by "can" by a lexical verbal that conveys the same idea:

> He should have been able to finish that work on time, shouldn't he?

Answer (score 1):

The English tag question is made up of **an auxiliary verb and a pronoun.** I searched on the Internet and could not find enough examples of the question-tags ending with a verb **in general**.

This said,

> You shouldn't have scolded the child, should you? -sounds better to me.

However, variant forms exist in different dialects (for instance, the tag *right* is common in Indian dialect). More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question).

Comment: Maulik, you are right about the composition of a question-tag. However, this one is an exception. Not an exception per se, but a verb with two auxiliaries - should and have. Hence, I am sure that the question-tag should be 'shouldn't you have'.

Comment: No, I am not interested in the tags. I am looking for formal usage only, as required in school-level examinations.

Comment: "You shouldn't scold the child, should you?" and "You shouldn't have scolded the child, should you?" Somehow, it doesn't sound right to use the same question tag in both cases.

Comment: @NeilD'Silva: Maulik is right. The only auxiliary to be considered is **should**. Have is part of the present perfect form of "scold".

Comment: @Laure Could you please shed some light on why 'should' is the only auxiliary that must be considered? That is the part that rankled me in the textual answer. I must say here that the people who have written the textbook have only a modicum of knowledge of grammar; it is full of mistakes.

Comment: If I take the sentence: You have scolded the child, the question-tag is "haven't you?" Here too 'have' is a part of the present perfect form of 'scold', isn't it? But it is considered.

Comment: @NeilD'Silva. Everybody will understand if you say "You should not have scolded the child, shouldn't you have?", there's nothing grammatically wrong with it, but it is not usual to have two auxiliaries in this sort of tags. The tag is built with the auxiliary that has the most influence on the sentence. In your example "has" only modifies "scold the child", it indicates the tense, modal "should" sheds light on the whole group "have scolded a child", the modal takes precedence over the tense auxiliary. "You can't have finished the cake, can you?" "He won't be coming late, will he?" etc.

Comment: @Laure if your comment was an answer I would vote for it.

Comment: @Laure I too would be quite happy to see that posted as an answer :)

Comment: @WendiKidd. I've tried not to make it just a repeat and add something to it.. hope it won't raise any objections. The whole thing about tag questions is much overdone in ESL/EFL teaching which gives learners the idea they're much more used than they are in reality. I've been thinking of writing a post about that on Meta.

Comment: @NeilD'Silva Most of the tests for auxiliary verbs in this clause point to *should* and not to the other auxiliary.  Here, *should* participates in subject-auxiliary inversion, it appears in tag questions, it can be negated, and it can be stressed to emphasize the polarity of the sentence, but none of these things are true of *have*.  This can be explained by calling *have* a complement of *should* rather than suggesting they're part of a flat structure with a list of auxiliaries of equal status.